# How to structure an array of multiple outputs in one array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

My code basically runs through an array, finds the maximum, and then locates the indices correlated with it. The issue I have is that I would like the indices in one array instead of multiple.

For example (actual output):

```
[1] [2] [3] [4]
```

Wanted output: `[1,2,3,4]`

Here is my code:

```
 int index;
    int num = myArray[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (num < myArray[i]) {
            num = myArray[i];
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
        if(num == myArray[j]){
               index = j;
               System.out.println("[" + j + "]");
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to do this without redoing all the code. Thanks.

Comment: So, your question is how to "print" the output as an array?

Comment: Are you looking to *create an array* containing the values 1,2,3,4 or just print the character string "[1,2,3,4]"?

Comment: I meant that array as an example output. I wanted the output as one array instead of separate arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
int index;
int num = myArray[0];
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (num < myArray[i]) {
        num = myArray[i];
    }
}
System.out.print("[");
int count = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
    if(num == myArray[j]){
           index = j;
           if(count++ > 0)
             System.out.print(",");
           System.out.print(j);
    }
}
System.out.println("]");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxValue = myArray[0];
int countMaxValues = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i] > maxValue) {
        maxValue = myArray[i];
        countMaxValues = 1;
    }
    else if (myArray[i] == maxValue) {
        countMaxValues++;
    }
}

int maxValueIndices = new int[countMaxValues];
int i = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
    if(myArray[j] == maxValue){
        maxValueIndices[i++] = j;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(maxValueIndices));
```